# Is burninating this tag a worthy [project]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

This is a *discussion*, not an invitation to unilaterally burninate the tag. Anyone that suggests ignoring or bypassing [the official process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination) risks moderator action, so let's avoid doing that.

---

I propose burninating the [project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project) tag (and the synonym, [projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/projects)). I feel this tag is extremely vague and is being used to tag any question connected to a "project". Tags should, mostly, describe what questions are about, not random other things they contain or are connected to, and I think this tag does the latter.

Wiki excerpt:

> In software development, a project is a collection of files and resources used in the development of an application or service. Use [ms-project] for Microsoft Project questions.

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

   This tag is ambiguous. It presumably means that whatever the question is about is part of some type of project, but that doesn't *describe* the actual question at all. It seems this tag describes what a question *contains* but not what it is *about*.
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

   Possibly, but this isn't a good tag for it. Managing a project via, say, [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) would be on-topic. But general questions about unspecified/arbitrary projects aren't.
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

   No.
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

   Nope. The OP is typically asking about something related to a project they're working on, but that's hardly "the same thing".
5. Is the tag causing a fairly large amount of harm?

   Possibly? It might encourage unclear questions, but I don't have any evidence that that is true.

A handful of questions referring to [Microsoft Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Project) may need to be tagged as [ms-project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-project), though.

So, should the [project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project) tag be burninated?

Comment: "*A handful of questions referring to Microsoft Project may need to be tagged as ms-project, though.*" I think this is taken care of now. I only found half a dozen or so that were about MS Project.

Comment: Is it possible for moderators to just completely nuke a tag, removing it from all questions without any replacement? I don't see *any* possible use of this tag where replacing it with something else would actually be worth anything. Just removing it should take care of almost all questions (except maybe those that only have one tag). That would make the burniation a lot quicker and not waste resources.

Comment: @MegaIng Nope, mods can't do that.  It's been done by staff before, but it's very rarely done, because it's rare that a tag is both popular _and_ conveys no useful information (which [I would argue that this one does](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/426805/208273)).  Another solution that's sometimes done is to blocklist the tag before it's removed, but that's also usually avoided due to it making editing existing questions with the tag more difficult (you have to remove it).

Comment: The phrasing of this question seems to miss that several IDEs have a specific concept called a "project", and that the tag appears to be about _that_ concept.

Comment: @RyanM Yes, or workspace. It is usually one or both since I know at least one IDE that lets you group projects inside a workspace.

Answer (score 18):

I would say yes.

There are so many different types of 'project' that calling your question about a 'project' does not narrow things down at all. For example, questions about Xcode projects could just be tagged [xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode), or Git projects can be tagged [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git), etc.

You could call just about any program a 'project' especially, as the tag guidance states, if it consists of multiple files and resources. I would say this tag is comparable to a [coding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/coding) tag. You cannot meaningfully be a subject-matter expert in [project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project).

This tag should be replaced with the different types of 'projects' supported by different platforms, such as [xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/xcode), [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git), etc.

Comment: Also, there's the (tiny) chance that someone reads it in the context of vector math (e.g. "projection matrix"), like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29816080/).

Comment: Using the [ms-project] tag to refer to a project using some Microsoft technology would be incorrect, as it refers to the [Microsoft Project](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Project) project-management tool.

Comment: I disagree with this answer to the extent that it advocates removing the tag (where it is used correctly to mean what the tag wiki describes) and not replacing it with anything, as it _does_ convey useful information about the question.

Comment: Project has a specific meaning in the context of programming, namely a gathering of source code in an IDE, for the purpose of generating an executable. It does not mean anything else or you are misusing the term. (A Git project for example ought to correspond to an IDE project, but not necessarily, since some out there still use make files.) Projects have been around since Turbo C in 1989 and perhaps further back still. There's no criteria that someone needs to be a subject expert of every tag, or [tag:bit], [tag:byte] etc would need to go too.

Answer (score 3):

This is partly an answer and partly a follow-up question.

The answer is:

- **We should rename this to something that clearly indicates that it refers to the concept of a project in an IDE or other editor**.  That *is* an on-topic subject about which users may have expertise, at least within a specific IDE.  It's also something about which there are a non-trivial number of questions (as an example, see [[project] [visual-studio]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/project+visual-studio)).

  - After doing so, we should clean up the tag, but right now mistagged questions are pouring in fast enough that we probably need to stem the bleeding to make this feasible.

The follow-up question:

- **What should such a tag be named?**  Ideally it should not be confusable, to someone who has only read the tag name and ignored the excerpt, with either Microsoft Project or the general concept of a project that you are working on.

Comment: In regards to a tag for a project in an IDE I'd like to think on whether we should really go that granular. Is a project in an IDE that specialized of a topic that we'd need a dedicated tag for the concept? Would the IDE's / editor's tag not be enough? Also for the specific example see: [tag:visual-studio-project]

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Maybe not.  Do you think that tag should also be a synonym for [visual-studio]?

Comment: Never really used Visual Studio so don't know if projects in it are that specialized of a concept. But in the general case I don't see the need.

Comment: I am unsure if there are many IDEs where the distinction between "using the IDE with a project" vs "using the IDE without a project" is common and meaningful in such a way that there is any value in adding the info that "this is within a project" is helpful compared to just "this is within the IDE"

Comment: @MegaIng Tags should be used when a question is _about_ something, so it should only be used for questions about _usage of the projects feature_, such as project creation, project configuration, the specifics of interactions between code across a project boundary, etc.

Comment: Good point. Have you seen this tag, though? It seems to be roughly what you're describing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/projects-and-solutions

Comment: @cocomac I had not, and it does, and that's a pretty good name...maybe just a synonym and/or merge to that is the solution? (pun not intended)

Comment: There's also web-project, which may also warrant discussion here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-project I don't have something in mind for it, but IMO it's quite closely connected here

Comment: @cocomac Based on the older questions, that's probably _supposed to be_ the same thing as [[tag:vs-web-site-project]] (which I just renamed from [web-site-project] because of this exact problem).

Comment: @RyanM I know, but my point is that I am unclear in what situation it isn't enough to know that something is an IDE. From my understanding, close to 100% of things in an IDE are project related, be that import management, name resolution, source file mangement. What features in an IDE can you ask on-topic questions about that aren't project related?

Comment: @MegaIng Syntax highlighting under Tools used by programmers, developing IDE plugins would be another (assuming enough details)

Comment: @MegaIng *"What features in an IDE can you ask on-topic questions about that aren't project related?"* Deployment to devices, debugging, most questions about import management or name resolution (in that they typically have nothing to do with projects even though they may occur _within_ one; also are most name resolution questions actually IDE questions?), IDE configuration, updates, profiling... I could go on.

Comment: @cocomac Unsure what on-topic questions there would be about syntax highlighting, except IDE debugging, which hopefully would be rare. Plugin development is a fair point.

Comment: @RyanM I would categorize all of those as belong to a project, and not making sense outside of the context of one. An IDE can't deploy something that doesn't belong to a project in some way. But maybe the terminology is so ambiguous that we have different definitions.

Comment: That several IDEs have "a concept called project" does little to defend this tag. On its own does nothing to define a scope of expertise. Experts on "Foo IDE" need only the "foo-ide" tag to find questions where they have expertise on. "Project" describes nothing, as a "project" on "Foo IDE" belongs to a different scope of expertise than a "project" on "Bar IDE", etc.

Comment: @MegaIng You are misunderstanding my point about how tags are supposed to be used.  You are talking about topics whose questions might contain code _from_ a project, but the question is not about usage of _the project feature itself_.  Similarly, just because you use Visual Studio to write a C# project does not mean you should tag [visual-studio] if the question is about the code itself.  You also wouldn't tag [operating-system] just because running C# doesn't make sense outside of an operating system.  An operating system is _involved_, but the question isn't _about_ the operating system.

Comment: Maybe "project-file" would be specific enough. This is often one or many physical files on the HD, but it is also a file in the context of an abstract thing used for storing source code. Still quite broad but at least made unambiguous vs project management etc.